# Which system configuration setting(s) on HP Compaq dc5750 need to be changed if "running Unix"?

Tags: system-installation, hardware

HP Compaq dc5750 small form factor Athlon 64 X2 3800+ 2.0GHz 2GB 160GB

On starting the system it displayed this message:

> If you are running Unix, you need to configure your system using the computer 
>   setup utility (F10)

Which system configuration setting(s) need to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/153985/what-bios-settings-must-i-change-on-a-compaq-dc5750-small-form-factor-to-install) for a possible answer.

I saw the same error with Z400 which is from HPE (compaq). This error message is likely due to a disk that looks like its a *nix formatted partition but its not bootable due to some issue with the drive contents. When this issue occurs, the BIOS spits out this ambiguous warning.